# Непонятное поведение при тестировании метода codeception

Tags: php, yii2, юнит-тесты, phpunit, codeception

Имеется модель , наследуемая от класса `yii\base\Model`, которая содержит в себе несколько AR моделей. Ниже привожу код модели.

```
class InquiryForm extends \yii\base\Model
{
    /**
     * @var ActiveRecord Адрес регистрации клиента
     */
    public $regAddress;

    /**
     * @var ActiveRecord Анкета
     */
    public $inquiry;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function load($data, $formName = null)
    {
        $load = [
            'inquiry' => $this->inquiry,
            'regAddress' => $this->regAddress,
        ];
        $success = false;

        foreach ($load as $name => $form) {
            $success = $form->load($data, $formName !== '' ? null : $name);
        }
        return $success;
    }
}
```

Я пытаюсь протестировать метод модели `load` c помощью `codeception`.

Привожу код тестов:
Для начала в методе `before()` отсоединяю модель AR от взаимодействия с базой, "мОкая" методы `save` & `attributes` следующим образом:

```
protected function _before()
{
    $this->_address = $this->createFormMock(Address::class,
        [
            'field1',
            'field2',
            'field3',
            'field4',
            'field5',
            'field6'
        ]
    );

    $this->_inquiry = $this->createFormMock(InquiryLogical::class,
        [
            'field1',
            'field2',
            'field3',
            'field4',
            'field5',
            'field6'
        ]
    );
}

protected function createFormMock(string $class, array $attributes)
{
    $mockObject = $this->getMockBuilder($class)
        ->setMethods(['save', 'attributes'])
        ->getMock();
    $mockObject->method('save')->willReturn(true);
    $mockObject->method('attributes')->willReturn($attributes);

    return $mockObject;
}
```

И наконец, пытаюсь протестировать метод:

```
    public function testLoadForm()
    {
        $data = [
            'there is some data from $_POST'
        ];

        $form = new InquiryForm(['inquiry' => $this->_inquiry, 
             'regAddress' => $this->_address]);

        $this->assertTrue($form->load($data));
    }
```

Первое время я очень долго не мог понять, почему мой простейший тест никак не отрабатывает и всё время выдает ошибку `Failed asserting that false is true.` Сначала думал, что как то некорректно создан `mockObject` или некорректные данные в массиве `$data`, но нет, 
там всё было правильно( при загрузке этих же данных на страничке всё корректно отрабатывает). 
Спустя некоторое время была обнаружена следующая интересная зависимость:

Если в тестируемом методе порядок загружаемых методов следующий:

```
$load = [
    'inquiry' => $this->inquiry,
    'regAddress' => $this->regAddress,
];
```

а в тесте я создаю объект формы вот таким образом:

```
$form = new InquiryForm(['inquiry' => $this->_inquiry, 
     'regAddress' => new Address()]);
```

то тест отрабатывает.

И наоборот, если в методе изменить порядок:

```
$load = [
    'regAddress' => $this->regAddress,
    'inquiry' => $this->inquiry,
];
```

а в тесте создавать объект формы следующим образом

```
$form = new InquiryForm(['inquiry' => new Inquiry(),  
    'regAddress' => $this->_address]);
```

то тест так же удачно отработает.

Это подтвержтает то, что мОки и тестовые данные созданы правильно. Но я не могу понять, почему так происходит? Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: А это нормьно что в одном случае вы обращаетесь к приватному свойству 'inquiry' => $this->_inquiry, а в другом 'inquiry' => new Inquiry() создаете новый экземпляр просто. Может в поведении класса гдето дальше используется $this->_inquiry, а оно null например.

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в коде `$success = $form->load($data, $formName !== '' ? null : $name);` т.е. `$success` всегда принимает последнее значение. Вам следует либо прервать цикл при `$success === false`, либо объединять результат с предыдущим. А моки у вас неправильные и мокать вы должны, если не ошибаюсь, метод `load`.

Comment: Егор, спасибо за ответ. Да, действительно это ошибка в логике метода, её нужно исправить. Но на саму проблему описанную в вопросе эта ошибка не влияет. Что касается моков, это почему же они неправильные? Мокаю я как раз те методы которые обращаются к БД. Зачем мне мокать `load`, если именно этот метод я тестирую.

Comment: Как же не влияют, когда вы делаете `$this->assertTrue($form->load($data));` и тест валится? Ваш тест проходит только если последняя итерируемая форма не мок. Мокать надо методы, которые исспользует метод, который вы тестируете. Вы тестируете `InquiryForm::load` он вызывает `load` для вложенных форм и `load` вам и надо мокать (то, что происходит там дальше тестируется в другом тесте, с другими моками).